# d3 v4 adding new nodes to force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js and I'm currently stuck on a problem. I'm using the force directed graph to show relationships of my data. This should allow a user to add a new node to the existing graph and draw a relationship link between 2 or more nodes. My caveat is my data is being populated from an ajax call which I assign to a variable and pass that to a function which generates the graph. The initial load of the data works great and everything is displayed properly. My issue is when the user clicks a button to add the new node. On that action I am making a ajax call to retrieve a new un-linked relationship to add to the graph. I add the new retrieved data to the nodes array and attempt to re-draw the entire graph. However I receive errors on x & y attributes being set to NaN. I believe this is related to how forceSimulation assigns those values. I did attempt to use simulation.reset(), but it was not successful.

Here is some of my code;

Initial call to retrieve all existing relationships.

```
function getGraphData(){
 $.ajax({
   url: [link to rest uri],
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/json'
 }).done(function(response){
   drawGraph(response);
 })
};
```

This is my second call to retrieve a new un-linked relationship

```
function getNewRelationshipData(){
  $.ajax({
    url: [link to second rest uri],
    type: 'GET'
    contentType: 'application/json'
  }).done(function(response){
    var newNode = response.nodes;
    updateGraph();
    //---same as getGraphData()
    $.ajax({
       url: [link to rest uri],
       type: 'GET',
       contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function(response){
       var graphData = response;
       graphData.nodes[graphData.nodes.length] = newNode[0]
       //assigned relationship data to graphData and appended the newNode value
       drawGraph(graphData);
    })
  });
};

function updateGraph(){
 // clears out old graph
 d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
};
```

This is how I'm setting up my graph.

```
function drawGraph(relationships){
 var svg = d3.select("svg"),
     w = +svg.attr("width"),
     h = +svg.attr("height);
 var g = svg.append("g");
 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

 var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(60))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2))
    .force("attraceForce",d3.forceManyBody().strength(-900));

 var opacity = 0.05;
 var transitionPeriod = 500;
 var graph = relationships;
 var link = g.selectAll("line")
 .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.value; })
    .style("stroke", "#999" )
    .style("opacity", "1")
    .attr("group",function(d) {return d.group; })
    .on("click", function(d) {
        // This is to toggle visibility - need to do it on the nodes, links & text
        d3.selectAll("line:not([group='"+d.group+"'])")
        .transition().duration(transitionPeriod).style("opacity", function() {
            var currentDisplay = d3.select(this).style("opacity");
            currentDisplay = currentDisplay == "1" ? opacity : "1";
            return currentDisplay;
        });
        d3.selectAll("circle:not([group='"+d.group+"'])")
        .transition().duration(transitionPeriod).style("opacity",function() {
            var currentDisplay = d3.select(this).style("opacity");
            currentDisplay = currentDisplay == "1" ? opacity : "1";
            return currentDisplay;
        });
        d3.selectAll("text:not([group='"+d.group+"'])")
        .transition().duration(transitionPeriod).style("opacity",function() {
            var currentDisplay = d3.select(this).style("opacity");
            currentDisplay = currentDisplay == "1" ? opacity : "1";
            return currentDisplay;
        });

    })

   var node = g
     .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 14)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
    .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended))

  var images = g.selectAll("image")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d){
      var type = d.type,
          typeIcon = "",
       switch(type){
       //assigns an image based on the subject type person, address, phone, ect.
       }
       return typeIcon;
    })
  // This is the label for each node
    var text = g.selectAll("text")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("dx",12)
        .attr("dy",".35m")
        .text(function(d) { return d.id;})
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("group",function(d) {return d.group;} ) ;

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    text
         .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
         .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});



//Used to drag the graph round the screen
function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

// This is the zoom handler
var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1/4, 4])
  .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

//specify what to do when zoom event listener is triggered
function zoom_actions(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

// initial scaling on the svg container - this means everything in it is scaled as well
svg.call(zoom_handler)
.call(zoom_handler.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(0.9,0.9))
;

zoom_handler(svg);
};
```

And my ajax data looks like this

```
{
 "nodes":[
  {"id": "1", "group": "1", "type": "person", "name":"Jon Doe"},
  {"id": "2", "group": "1", "type": "person", "name":"Jane Doe"}
  //ect list of ~50
 ],
 "links":[
  {"source": "1", "target":"2"},
  //ect list of ~50
 ]
}
```

I hope someone with more d3.js experience can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this there in case someone else had the same problem. I solved my problem by breaking up the drawGraph function into smaller widgets.

I moved the following to the parent scope.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      w = +svg.attr("width"),
      h = +svg.attr("height),
      node,
      link;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(60))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2))
    .force("attraceForce",d3.forceManyBody().strength(-900));

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
```

Then within the drawGraph function I made the following changes.

```
function drawGraph(nodes,links){
   var g = svg.append("g");
   link = g.selectAll(".link").data(links,function(d){ return d.target.id; })
   link = link.enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class","link")
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.value; })
        .style("stroke", "#999")

   node = g.selectAll(".node").data(nodes,function(d){ return d.id; })
   node = node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","node")
        .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended))
   node.append("circle").attr("r", 14).attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.group);})
   node.append("text").attr("dy", -15)
       .text(function(d){ return d.id; })
       .attr("text-anchor","middle")
       .style("fill", "#555");

   node.append("image")
       .attr("xlink:href",function(d){
          var type = d.type,
          typeIcon = "",
          switch(type){
            //assigns an image based on the subject type person, address, phone, ect.
           }
       return typeIcon;
      })
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y", -8)
      .attr("height", 16)
      .attr("width", 16);

 simulation.nodes(nodes).on("tick", ticked);
 simulation.force("link").links(links);

 function zoom_actions(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
 };

 var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1/4, 4])
  .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

 svg.call(zoom_handler).call(zoom_handler.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(0.9,0.9));

zoom_handler(svg);

};

function ticked() {
 link
     .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
     .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
     .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
     .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

 node
     .attr("transform", function(d) { 
           return "translate("+ d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; 
      });
};

 function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

I then added the following function which is used to setup the data and draw the graph.

```
function formatGraphData(relationships){
 nodes = relationships.nodes;
 links = relationships.links;
 simulation.alpha(0.5).restart(); //<- needed to restart simulation and position nodes
 drawGraph(nodes,links);
}
```

Then the ajax calls were updated to use formatGraphData instead of drawGraph.

I added the following to my css file

```
.links line{
 stroke: #999;
}
.nodes circle{
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```